# What are the security risks when using free Content delivery networks (CDNs)?

Tags: web-application, risk-management, web-service

I was doing some research on Content Delivery Networks. For those who don't know, a CDN is a large collection of servers that cache and quickly serve up static content such as images, css, js, etc, to end users. CDNs can significantly increase performance by not only caching content but by also limiting the number of network hops to retrieve content.

I'm considering using free CDNs but I was surprised to find next to zero articles, blogs, or forums concerning potential security risks when using them. What are the risks of using free CDNs? How are those risk mitigated?

Comment: I think your question lacks a few important details. What is your exact use case, for example?

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of the free CDNs you are considering?

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/7843/5501

Comment: you can use the `integrity` attribute on <script> tags to ensure that they are what you expect.

Answer (score 12):

Since you are usually loading CSS, JavaScript and graphics from a CDN anyone with root-like permissions on the CDN servers (i.e. the company running the CDN) can:

- replace your images with other ones, such as porn or other things you don't want your users to see on your website
- replace your CSS to load said images, mess up the design, etc. - for IE and Mozilla/Firefox users the CSS could also cause arbitrary JavaScript code to be executed
- replace your JavaScript to annoy your user, redirect to other sites, possibly load exploit code to infect them with trojans
- (have technical problems causing your site's assets to load much slower than normally)

So all in all, only use a CDN you trust enough not to do those things.

Comment: "_replace your CSS to load said images, mess up the design, etc._" CSS can also contain JS!

Comment: *"for IE users the CSS could also cause arbitrary JavaScript code to be executed"* (via `behavior`) - did I miss a way that works in other browsers?

Comment: @ThiefMaster It's possible in Firefox, too. See Zach's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476276/using-javascript-in-css

Comment: @Polynomial: that hasn't worked in years and years, and firefox is usually fresh... It also doesn't work in IE11 without other mistakes being made.

Comment: @dandavis Expressions now work in most browsers, though.

Comment: @Polynomial: I really don't think that's the case, at all. Can you provide a demo so we can see it in action?

Answer (score 11):

@ThiefMaster's answer does a great job of enumerating the risks of using an externally controlled Content-- which basically fall under the category of executing or displaying arbitrary code and content on a user's browser.

I will mainly focus on your last question: `How are those risk mitigated?` which was unaddressed-- a lot has since changed (in 4 years).

The primary defense when including external resources from a CDN is to use [Subresource Integrity (SRI)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-SRI-20160623/). SRI extends two HTML elements with an integrity attribute that contains a cryptographic hash of the representation of the resource the author expects to load. Specifically, these are the `<script>` and `<link>` elements, commonly used to include third-party Javascript and CSS respectively.

Examples:

***CSS:***

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

***JS:***

> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous">

One or multiple hashes can be used, generally generated with openssl with base64 encoding. A browser uses the "strongest" one that it supports.

This is now supported [by Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6183089948590080) and [by Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity).

When these browsers encounter an SRI-protected element, they compute the digest and return a network error if it does not match the expected result. To protect against an update on a CDN, [failovers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/subresource-integrity-in-firefox-43/) can be setup, either to other CDNs or to your own server.

Another defense you can note above is the use of the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute. This prevents your browser from sending cookies to the CDN,  thus avoiding [CORS leaks](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/#cross-origin-data-leakage) with a side effect of reducing the request size.

Finally, a very slight benefit could be found by setting a restrictive `Content-Security-Policy` that limits the attack surface only to the CDN, such that even if a vulnerable CDN was infected by a different JS file, it will not directly be able to access the data (though it could through the CDN).

Apart from the various links above, another useful reference is this [Mozilla Hacks article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/subresource-integrity-in-firefox-43/).